# When some idempotent ideals belong to the Gabriel filter of ideals for a hereditary torsion theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, modules, torsion-theory

Let $\mathscr{I}_\sigma$ be the Gabriel filter of ideals for a hereditary torsion theory $\sigma$  over a commutative ring $R$. I am looking for equivalent conditions on either $\sigma$ or $R$ under which for each idempotent element $e$ of $R$ either $\langle e\rangle\in \mathscr{I}_\sigma$ or $\langle 1-e\rangle\in \mathscr{I}_\sigma$.

> Note that a Gabriel filter of ideals $\mathscr{I}_\sigma$ , a non–empty filter of ideals satisfying that every ideal
> $I$ of $R$, for which there exists an ideal $J\in\mathscr{I}_\sigma$  such that $(I : j):=\{r\in R\mid rj\in I\}\in\mathscr{I}_\sigma$ , for every
> $j\in J$, belongs to $\mathscr{I}_\sigma$ .

Comment: I suspect that the notation and terminology you're using might not be defined in _exactly_ the same way by all authors. For the benefit of those reading (and potentially answering) the question, it might be worthwhile to remind us of some of the definitions (such as the notion of a Gabriel filter, perhaps even the notion of a hereditary torsion theory) and notation (such as the angle brackets), or else cite / link to places where we can brush up. It might also not hurt to provide a bit of context or an example of an $R$ you care about, especially since the question is a bit open-ended.